# Can't get string "value" from if statement -- C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to read the contents of a file into a single string with an if statement. I'm using the if statement to make sure the file is properly opening. I'm able to successfully read contents of the file but I'm not able to print/use the string outside of the if statement.

```
    std::string test;
    std::ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << myfile.rdbuf();
        std::string test = buffer.str();
        //std::cout << test << std::endl; // <--- string prints out fine here
    }

    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";


    std::cout << test << std::endl; // <--- nothing happens here
```

I thought declaring the variable before the if statement was all I needed to do but it isn't working for me. I'm sure the answer is easy and this question doesn't really need to be asked i just can't figure this out right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers

Comment: yeah sorry about that I switched it back seeing as all the answers are for how i originally wrote it

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a declaration, just do an assignment in the `if`:

```
std::string test;
std::ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << myfile.rdbuf();
    test = buffer.str();  //No std::string before test
}

std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a duplicate local variable "test" with same name as the outside "test", all change you made will apply on the local "test":

```
std::string test;
std::ifstream myfile ("example.txt");

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << myfile.rdbuf();
    std::string test = buffer.str(); // <--- string content is convert to local variable "test"
    //std::cout << test << std::endl; 
}

std::cout << test << std::endl; // <--- test variable here is still remained empty
```

Comment: Well I appreciate knowing where I went wrong. I thought declaring the variable outside got me 1 step closer to my goal. When I remove that it says test is undeclared so I guess my question is: how can I "extract" a variable I declared in an if statement.

Comment: It would have if you'd changed it instead of *shadowing* it. `test = ...` assigns to an existing variable, while `std::string test` creates a new one with exactly the same name, though it is scoped to that particular block, so the old one comes out of the shadows, as it were, once you exit.

Comment: I switched the name outside to test2 and made it = test. Idk if thats the best way but it worked for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @EB921 The issue is why you think you need a variable declaration inside the if statement. Just remove that declaration, not the declaration outside.